# Didn't get response on browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, web-deployment, nodejs-server

I write a code for to read json file and print it to browser. The code working fine it print data on console. but didn't get on browser.

```
app.post("/uploadfile",function (req, res, next) {
    
// Error MiddleWare for multer file upload, so if any
// error occurs, the image would not be uploaded!
upload(req,res,function(err) {

    if(err) {
        res.send(err)
    }
    else {

        //res.sendFile(__dirname+"/result.html")

        // Read users.json file
        fs.readFile(__dirname+"/uploads/zipFile.json", function(err, data) {

        // Check for errors
        if (err) throw err;

        // Converting to JSON
        const msg = JSON.parse(data);

        console.log(msg)

        app.post('/', function(req, res){
        res.send(msg);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, Your problems was in `app.post('/', function(req, res){` line.

Please remove that line and test it's work or not.

```
app.post("/uploadfile",function (req, res, next) {
    
// Error MiddleWare for multer file upload, so if any
// error occurs, the image would not be uploaded!
upload(req,res,function(err) {

    if(err) {
        res.send(err)
    }
    else {

        //res.sendFile(__dirname+"/result.html")

        // Read users.json file
        fs.readFile(__dirname+"/uploads/zipFile.json", function(err, data) {

        // Check for errors
        if (err) {
          res.send(err);
          return;
        }

        // Converting to JSON
        const msg = JSON.parse(data);

        console.log(msg)

        res.send(msg);

...
```